# How to implement a C++ observer pattern in Objective C

Tags: c++, objective-c, interface, observer-pattern

I am trying to implement Objective C wrappers for certain C++ classes. One of these classes has implemented an observer pattern and requires an observer to be of a certain C++ type (defined in the interface).

I Googled all day now but could not find anything related to this issue. How can I subscribe to this C++ observer pattern with an Objective C class? One would need to use inheritance for this to work but this obviously cannot work since the Wrapper is Objective C and cannot inherit from a C++ interface.

Comment: You can't. Objective C and C++ are not compatible with each other. Try Objective C++.

Comment: Could you add an example usage of your observer?

Answer (score 1):

Why does the observer need to inherit from your obj-c class? Can't instances of the objective-c class just have an observer that forwards on to the objective-c object?

Answer (score 0):

> One would need to use inheritance for this to work but this obviously
>   cannot work since the Wrapper is Objective C and cannot inherit from a
>   C++ interface

That is an incorrect statement, wrappers wrap they do not inherit. If you need to use C++ you need to use Objective-C++ by creating a file with a `.mm` extension.

Comment: > wrappers wrap they do not inherit

True, so it seems I would need to make another C++ class which inherits from the interface and Wrap that one?

Comment: Yes if inheritance is necessary then you would need to inherit with another C++ class, then if you want an Objective-C wrapper that will call the inherited class.